# Help with mounting a TV over a window

Tags: windows, mounting, television

I would like to mount my television over a window. I identified this mount; [Chief OB1U](https://www.legrandav.com/products/chief/mounts/display/wall-fixed/ob1/ob1u)

It looks like it will do the trick, except that the opening of my window is approximately 60" high and the max length of the mount is approximately 66". It needs to be mounted in at least two studs but over the window I understand contains a header and I'm guessing it is taller than the range of the mount.

So my question is, can the header withstand the weight and force from this mount and 75lbs of television?

Here is a picture of the opening I will be placing the tv;
[image: Window]

Comment: The header can easily hold the weight. My question would be why are you picking this style of TV mounting system.  It is designed to fit over a whiteboard.  That's the reason the top and bottom mounting points are so spread out.  The selected mounting system also do no allow a tilt do the optimum viewing is at the ceiling, not looking up at the TV.  You need a mount that allows the TV to be tilted down.   Do you have enough space above the window to use the mounting system of your selected mount?

Comment: The tilt won't be an issue because the  TV will be at the correct height as is the one in the picture. The reason for selecting this type of mount is that I don't want the space of a stand, a pull down would make the TV too high, and I need to mount over the window.

Comment: Now I get it, You want it in FRONT of the window.  I can only insert pictures in Ans.  I used a ceiling mount, cost about $60.  With the ceiling mount, you can rotate and tilt the TV.  Very clean looking.  TV looks like it is floating.   I can only insert pictures in Ans.  Will attach pic later so you can see.

Comment: I looked at ceiling mounts but even the longest I saw seemed like the TV would be too high. The pole mounts that go from floor to ceiling would probably work but then it would defeat the purpose (clearing up floor space)

Comment: Seating upright in a lounger, my head is tilted back slightly and looks directly at the center of the TV.  When the lounger is laid back, the eye is angle even more toward the ceiling.  The mount I have may extend more, but I would need other people to help me to see how much further it could be extended down.  The bottom of the tv is 34" off the floor.

Comment: Will you have a HD camera outside feeding the TV so you can still enjoy the window view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will not be an issue. The header is almost surely over-sized as it is not designed to just barely support the design weight but rather it is up-sized to the next sized header that is being used on the project. Even if it was a max capacity, 75 lbs is relatively small compared to the amount of load that the header is designed for.

Comment: I guess my main concern is that the header is meant to hold the downward force of the joists and such, but this would be a pulling force on the front of it.

Comment: there will be jack studs opposing the large downward force and only nails holding against the pulling force, but the nails will be plenty strong enough.

Comment: one of the nails will resist ~100# each and there are usually many at each end, in the range of 5-10 or more, for a total of 10-20. The header is nailed to (king) studs which are nailed to the top plate 2 or 3 nails at each end for a total of 4-6 nails, plus any nails along the top plate to the header. The top plate is connected to the roof, it's not going anyway from 75#. Good on you to be concerned, but it is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

Per your question, the header and studs below the window can easily hold the 75# weight.
 
For a much cleaner look, I would look into a ceiling tv mount.  With the ceiling mount, you can rotate and tilt the TV. Very clean looking. TV looks like it is floating.  This is a 70" tv, also in the 75-100# range. Attached are two pictures of the TV w ceiling mount.

To address your concern about about ceiling mounting not extending down enough, this [mount](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073X5PKYD) extends over 6' from the ceiling.

1st is with the panels moved to the side so you can see the top and bottom of the window.  Red outline the full window.
 
[image]

2nd picture is with the panels closed.

[image]

Comment: Looking at your TB current mounted on the TV table,  My tv is hanging about the height about the tv stand.

Comment: Wish I saw your link before I ordered the over window mount. My ceiling is 9 feet high. So 6 feet would be more than enough.